# How to use NerdTree to automatic focus on the current opened file position when toggle it on?

Tags: buffers, plugin-nerdtree

When use vim with nerdtree, I opened a file in a project. Press `<Leader>` key to trigger `NERDTreeToggle`. On the left side it will list the whole project directory by default.

[image]

I want to let it focus on the opened file's absolute path automatically without unfold the root directory again. Can it do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the NERDTreeFind command instead of NERDTreeToggle.

Comment: Thank you for the right solution!